# I have enabled authentication and still can connect without username and password to MongoDB

Tags: configuration, authentication, mongodb

I have the following in my /etc/mongod.conf:

```
# set parameter options
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false

# security options
security:
  authorization: enabled
  #keyFile: replace_me
```

I have restarted mongod service using `systemctl restart mongod` and checked /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log. There is a recent line about config was readed and settings in effect:

```
{
  "t": { "$date": "2023-11-26T10:39:15.483+00:00" },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "CONTROL",
  "id": 21951,
  "ctx": "initandlisten",
  "msg": "Options set by command line",
  "attr": {
    "options": {
      "config": "/etc/mongod.conf",
      "net": {
        "bindIp": "*",
        "ipv6": false,
        "port": 27017,
        "tls": {
          "certificateKeyFile": "/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem",
          "mode": "requireTLS"
        }
      },
      "processManagement": {
        "fork": false,
        "pidFilePath": "/var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.pid"
      },
      "security": { "authorization": "enabled" },
      "setParameter": { "enableLocalhostAuthBypass": "false" },
      "storage": { "dbPath": "/var/lib/mongodb", "directoryPerDB": false },
      "systemLog": {
        "destination": "file",
        "logAppend": true,
        "logRotate": "reopen",
        "path": "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log",
        "quiet": false,
        "verbosity": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**It seems my settings are in effect.
Why I can still log in to my mongod service without username and password?**